# Why am I getting the error "QuarzCore/QuartzCore.h not found"?

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics, xcode4.6

I am new to iOS development and trying to build an app for the device. It gives me the error "QuartzCore.h not found". However, when I try to build the same for the Simulator, it works fine.

I tried adding the QuartzCore.Framework in the build phases tab, but this framework was not showing up.

Comment: is the library `QuartzCore.framework`in your `Buid Phases / Link Binary with Library`?

Comment: yes... I verified it already. Its not there.

Comment: I mean I tried to include... but the framework not available in the list... thats the problem

Comment: Have you the last xcode version?

Comment: My current XCode version is 4.6.2

Comment: I am having the same problem now. It was working fine only.But today for me it is showing <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> file not found.But it is getting listed for simulator and not for device when I try to do link binary with libraries @rahul Has your problem solved?
And my xcode version is 4.3.2

Answer (score 3):

After including the QuartzCore framework in build phases, you need to import it into your class files as follows:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Notice the '<', '>' characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you still can't find the problem, you can create a new Xcode project and import the QuartzCore framework. If this solves the problem, migrate to the new project. If not, your Xcode may have a problem.